# Read response even though it's 404

Tags: java, http-status-code-404

Is there a way to read a response of a simple http-get made like below, if getResponseCode() == 404 and thus getInputStream() would throw an exception? I'd prefer to stay with java.net, if it's possible.

```
HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection)new URL("http://somesite.com").openConnection;
c.openInputStream();
```

Thing is, that I have (indeed) a site I want to read out with java that responds with 404, but displays in a browser, because it obviously caries a response anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use the [`getErrorStream()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getErrorStream%28%29) if the `getResponseCode() == 404`.

```
HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection)new URL("http://somesite.com").openConnection();
InputStream in = null;
if (c.getResponseCode() >= 400) {
   in = c.getErrorStream();
}  
else {
   in = c.getInputStream();
}
```

Comment: That returns null. I should have been more specific about the response: it seems like everything is okay with it except that the response code is set to 404 for some reason. But it has to be okay otherwise, because Firefox and Chrome display the site correctly.

Comment: @Hellnail I just tested that code against my site which has a very large custom 404 error page and I was able to read the page.

Comment: You can use getErrorStream() method but you have to initiate the connection first otherwise, it returns null. You can do it by calling getInputStream() or getResponseCode() as stated in this answer.